# Error: Call to undefined function

Tags: php, mysql

This is my coding for deleting a row from a php table.

```
<html>
    <?php
        include("DBConfig/Db_connection.php");  
        if(isset($_POST['Reassign'])){
            if(isset($_POST['checkbox']))
            {
                $id = $_POST['Reassign'];
                $id1 = $_POST['checkbox'];
                $sql = "INSERT INTO archived SELECT * FROM faults WHERE id='$id1';";
                $sql .=  "DELETE FROM faults WHERE id='$id1'; "; 
                $sql = mysql_multiquery($sql,$dbcon);
                if (!$mysqli->multi_query($sql)) {
                    echo "Multi query failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
                }
                else{
                    echo "Assigned successfully";
                }           
            }       
        }

        ?>

    <script>
    function mysql_multiquery($queries,$conn)
    {
        $queries = explode(";", $queries);
        foreach ($queries as $query)
            $query = mysql_query(trim($query),$conn);

    }
    </script>   
    </html>
```

This gives me the error call to undefined function mysql_multiquery().
Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: Because that function doesn't exist? P.s. you can't mix and match mysql_* and mysqli_* .

Comment: try `mysqli_multi_query` instead

Comment: a javascript function cannot be called directly in PHP, it is just text for him (PHP executes what's in `<?php` tags)

Comment: You can't call javascript function as a PHP function!!! PHP is added as a javascript function :P Change `script` tag to PHP function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st :** Because your wrapping php code in `<script>` tag .so php will not parse that `function` so it's throwing that `Call to undefined function` .

**2nd :** No need this line `$sql = mysql_multiquery($sql,$dbcon);` because in next line your executing mysqli `multi query` . `$mysqli->multi_query($sql)`

Comment: It's giving me the following error
Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\OSS_Fault_Mgt\assignRecord.php on line 10

Comment: `$mysqli` is not your connection `object` ? @sj111 .show you `DB_connection.php` code too

Comment: <?php  
$dbcon=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");  
mysqli_select_db($dbcon,"oss_fault_mgr");  
?>

Comment: change to `<?php $mysqli=mysqli_connect("localhost","root",""); mysqli_select_db($mysqli,"oss_fault_mgr"); ?>`

Comment: Right! Tnx. It's working now. :) Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, 
I need help with modifying the above code for multiple records. It's only working for a single record.

Comment: for multiple record just use `foreach loop`

Answer (score 0):

you can't write php functions wrap inside script tags. PHP do not recognize that. If you want to execute multiple query then use `mysqli_multi_query`

```
$sql = mysqli_multi_query($sql,$dbcon);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Wrapping PHP code in `<script>` tags makes no sense. It won't be read by PHP.
- Your function is useless nevertheless since you call mysql_multi_query in your condition in the very next line.
- `mysql_*` functions shouldn't be used, they are unsafe. Their used is discouraged for a decade, deprecated since PHP5.6 and removed since PHP7.0 and put your whole code at risk of SQL injection. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.